# Karate - How to use karate-config.js variables in java file?

Tags: karate

I have a DB utils java file  where I need to load DB username password based on environment I am running the code on , and these environment values I need to import from karate-config.js . How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use embedded expressions ! So if you have `dbusername` and `dbpassword` set in `karate-config.js`:

```
* def config = { username: '#(dbusername)', password: '#(dbpassword)', url: 'jdbc:h2:mem:testdb', driverClassName: 'org.h2.Driver' }
* def DbUtils = Java.type('com.mycompany.DbUtils')
* def db = new DbUtils(config)
```